# Accessing AppDelegate from framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-frameworks

I'm creating my first framework in Objective-C that wraps the facebook SDK in a more intuitive way. There are several points in my framework where I'd like to reference the AppDelegate, but there is no appdelegate when you create a static Cocoa Touch library. How can I reference it? I want to reference the app delegate of the xcode project that my framework is linked to.

Comment: You weak link the UIKit framework, get the UIApplication singleton, and ask it for its delegate. (All your included frameworks should be weak linked - forget the exact term - don't force them to link in your framework.)

Answer (score 3):

If you're creating a framework the whole idea is to make it portable. Tying a framework to the app delegate defeats the purpose of building a framework. What is it you need the app delegate for?

Comment: I want to wrap the facebook sdk. Right now,to integrate your app with Facebook, the user has to copy and paste a bunch of lines to their app delegate and i want to wrap those lines into single keywords. Why would tying a framework to the app delegate defeat portability? Thanks for helping a noob out.